# graph api get post max limit 30 and nothing filter?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to ask a facebook timeline with php sdk.

```
$this->FaceBookApp = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
            "app_id" => $this->appId,
            "app_secret" => $this->appSecret,
            "default_graph_version" => $this->defaultGraphVersion
));
$this->FaceBookApp->setDefaultAccessToken($this->appId .'|'. $this->appSecret);

$Fields = "fields=type,message,source,picture,created_time,name,link,description,is_published";
$response = $this->FaceBookApp->get('/'.$this->userId.'/posts?limit=100&'.$Fields, $this->appId .'|'. $this->appSecret);
$list = $response->getDecodedBody();
$this->workingList = $list["data"];
```

count($this->workingList) = 36;

regardless of the value of the limit, but the Graph API Explorer returns 100 results.

and the filter does not work.
And:

```
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
$nextFeed = $this->FaceBookApp->next($feedEdge);
```

$nextFeed = NULL !!

how can i get the last 100 post or how can i filter list?

thanx